# Is there an advantage of using HTML5 calculations over JS, or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, html

New in HTML 5 is a framework to perform calculations, using, among others, `<output>`.

Before this, you would use Javascript for everything, including presenting the output.

Is there any advantage of using HTML 5 Calculations over JS (or vice versa)?

Obviously JS can do more complicated things, as well as use numbers retrieved from other places, but are there any others?

Comment: If a user disables JS, won't the HTML5 calculations still be executed?

Comment: No, not that I know of. I prefer to leave the HTML as structure and JS as the functionality.

Comment: `<output>` is just an element to manipulate *with JS* for show the results of calculations. What else are you referring to by "framework to perform calculations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<output>` isn't used to *perform* calculations, it is used to *express the result*.

The calculation is still performed by JS, you just have an element with new semantics and a helpful DOM interface to present them to the reader.

Comment: Oh. Evidently I got the wrong impression. I have updated the question anyway.

Comment: Now the question doesn't make much sense. What framework? And you wouldn't use JS for presenting the output, at least no more then you do if you are using `<output>` (it is still DOM manipulation).

Comment: Oh, just ignore me. I don't seem to know what I'm talking about. What I meant, is if it still uses JS, then the new tags must be like a "framework" to help implement the JS. just ignore me. I doubt I'll ever use these anyway.